# Django query how to write: WHERE field LIKE '10__8__0__'?

Tags: django, django-models

There is ***contains*** method, but it means: `WHERE field LIKE '%10%'`. And I need exactly `WHERE field LIKE '10__8__0__'`.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I mean string is `'10xx8xx0xx'`, where x - any symbol

Comment: do it by `raw`, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#django.db.models.Manager.raw

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do this with [django-like](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-like):

```
MyModel.objects.filter(field__like='10%8%0%')
```

Also I created a related ticket on the [Django project site](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17473)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to clarify what I want to do. See my EDIT

Comment: This works, but since I was going to search for '%query%', I decided to just use field__contains

Comment: This is more flexible than __contains, why not it wasn't included in Django by default? it should be added in django and not replace __contains.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to do the search you intend to do is by regular expression:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(field__regex=r'^10..8..0..$')
```

**Edit:**

My solution is possibly much slower than LIKE. The problem though is that the django ORM does not allow easy access to `LIKE`. It'd be easiest if `startswith` or `endswith` were sufficient for your purposes.

Comment: It's much slower than `LIKE`, at least for MySQL.

Comment: This works, but is not as efficient as like. Why do not exists something like this? MyModel.objects.filter(field__like='10%8&0%'). If the ORM do not scape the string you can to do this: MyModel.objects.filter(field='10%8&0%')

Comment: @DrTyrsa is much slower, but it is also your solution o_O. Your solution after the Till-Backhaus solution

Comment: +1 Try regex first. If it turns out to be too slow, then you can use [`extra()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra)

Comment: I get to do something like this: MyModel.objects.filter(field__like="10%%8%%0%%"). But now is a dirty solution. I want create a app to get this, and will be a clean and beautiful solution. I think that tomorrow or day after tomorrow I will publish this.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`extra`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra) to do this:

```
MyModel.objects.extra(where=["column_name LIKE '%10%"])
```

Note that `column_name` is the column name in the database, rather than the field name in your Django model. In many cases, the field name and column name will be the same, but if they differ, take care to use the column name.

Answer (score -2):

In SQL, you can query it like:

```
WHERE field LIKE '10??8??0??'
```

Try that in your Django filter.

Comment: This is impossible with the default lookups in django.Therefore I implement django-like http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-like