# Django models queryset with array

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I want to make a function which will return applications which names contains some text.

Let's assume that we have below models:

```
class Application(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_lenght=100)

Example values: "T2 AAA", "T2 BBB", "FSA KK" etc.
```

Now I want to write function which should return me application T2 AAA if attribute of this function will be AAA:

```
def getApplication(request, title):
    titleVars = title.split(' ')
    applications = Application.objects.filter(name__in=titleVars)
```

Honestly I don't know how to do that, I think that I should use `icontains` however I don't know how it applies to the array `titleVars`.

Example execution:

`getApplication(request, 'Some text whatever T2 AAA XXX/K')`

Thanks in advance

Comment: name__in does not work?

Comment: Perhaps use [Q()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q).

Comment: `name_in` doesn't work because we are checking if "T2 AAA" is in the array ["T2", "AAA"].

@Alex, but how should I use it ?

Comment: Hint - I think you are looking for like search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for like search.

Using `Q()` -

```
from django.db.models import Q

obj_list = Application.objects.filter(reduce(lambda x, y: x | y, [Q(name__contains=word) for word in titleVars]))
```

And thats the recommended way.

Other options -

You can do this with [django-like](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-like) (ref - [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644146/django-query-how-to-write-where-field-like-10-8-0)):

```
Application.objects.filter(name__like=titleVars[1])
```

Other way is you can loop thru your array item, and do regex check.

Comment: I will check the first answer.
The second one is not the one I am looking for, looping thru the array is not a good idea.

Comment: Yup, Q() one is recommended.

Comment: @Silwestpl- Any luck with the solution?

Comment: It is almost good answer but the problem is when I write 'T2 AAA', it finds T2 AAA, T2 BBB, T2 CCC etc. :(

Comment: Yes, you are right but the point is that I would like to find only the applications which match second part AAA, I think that I will remove t2 from the array ...

Comment: You can remove the first element before the match. Or construct the list before applying reduce lambda function.